# Why "to" in "I’ve been leaving the worst to last" and what does it mean?

Tags: meaning

> (I remember he once said about a Mondrian—“it isn’t whether you like it, but whether you ought to like it”—I mean, he dislikes abstract art on principle. He ignores what he feels.)
>
> I’ve been leaving the worst **to** last. Women.

From *The Collector*, by John Fowles

Why "**to** last" and what does it mean?

Comment: Could you provide us with additional context, maybe perhaps the full quotation from where you found this sentence? As it stands, the quote seems either grammatically incorrect or awkward, depending on how you define **last**.

Comment: Is that how you found the quote? Is it from The Collector? Please always indicate the source of the text and include any relevant surrounding context so that users can have enough details to answer your questions accurately. Otherwise, your questions may be closed. See [_Details, Please_](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The more commonly used variation of this idiom nowadays is probably:

> I've been leaving the worst *until* last.

The meaning of this phrase is that, when faced with a number of tasks perhaps, you have deliberately left the most difficult or unpleasant one until last. It is the reverse of a similar phrase "save the *best* until last", which is normally only used when dealing with nice things. So, rather like the saying "*the lesser of two evils*" your phrase in question suggests that there are many bad things, but this is the worst.

You asked why, in your quote it uses "*to*" instead of "*until*". Variations of this phrase might also use "*for*". It just depends on the context - that is whatever you are speaking about.

Your quotation is from *The Collector* by John Fowles, and the context is that the narrator is speaking about a man named G.P. with whom he has various issues. He finds his criticism of art to be invalid, and questions his morals regarding women. It is after he has talked for some length about G.P's failings that he says "*I've been leaving the worst until last. Women*".

So basically he has been talking about all his faults, and he has left what he considers to be the worst *to* talk about last, namely G.P's attitude towards women.

Comment: This is from original english novel. Then what is the meaning of this phrase in the context?

Comment: I understood what means “to last”, but still what is main message of whole context? Is she afraid that he does not like women (the worst) as the last item?

Comment: @Vitaly Now that you have added more context I have been able to update my answer.

Comment: Thank you Astralbee, I see. In this book John Fowles speaks this phrase on behalf of Meranda (a yang 20 years old girl).  It turns out the yang girl reflected the views of the writer. I think the main meaning of the book is that rich dull men prevent smart people from living free.

Comment: @Vitaly Okay well if it was helpful could you consider voting for or possibly even accepting the answer?

Comment: Yes, how to do this? I am a biginner on this site.

Comment: @Vitaly To the left of each answer there are UP + DOWN buttons for voting, and if it is your question you will also have a TICK or CHECK button to mark the answer you accept.

Answer (score 0):

It means the speaker has been giving the listener a list of items, and has purposely arranged the order of that list so that the worst item (typically, worst from the point of view of at least the listener) is at the end; i.e. it is the last item.

Comment: Then what is the meaning of this phrase in the context with regard to  "Women."?